# WPF Page Anchor Links

Tags: wpf

Is there a way to navigate WPF pages with anchor links?  I have a large page for my application and without having to split it up I'd like to be able to scroll it and also jump to specific header areas.

thanks!

Comment: Tried to set focus on header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "possible" solution is to use [FrameworkElement.BringIntoView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598110.aspx) which attempts to bring the target element into view, within any scrollable regions it is contained within.